# My word count program is not working

Tags: java, arraylist, bufferedreader, filereader, word-count

The code below is meant to count the number of times the words in list y occur either in a document via `FileReader` or list x. Eventually I want list y to be an imported document as well, but when I run the code on a document it either gives me a false count or no count at all. What’s going on?

Also the files are form notepad. I'm using windows

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class test {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        don w = new don();

        List<Integer> ist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        // List<String> x =Arrays.asList
        // ("is","dishonorable","dismal","miserable","horrible","discouraging","distress","anguish","mine","is");

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("this one.txt"));
        String str;

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            list.add(str);
            // System.out.println(list);
            List<String> y = Arrays.asList("Hello", "the", "string", "is", "mine");
            for (String aY : y) {
                int count = 0;
                for (String aX : list) {
                    if (aY.contains(aX)) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                ist.add(count);
                // no need to reset the count
            }
            int g = ist .stream()
                        .mapToInt(value -> value)
                        .sum();
            System.out.println(g);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the `don` object is supposed to do. You instantiate it buy, you do nothing with it afterwards. I don't understand why you store `count` on an `ArrayList`

Comment: the don is part of the program I meant to take out when asking this question because it's not related. I'm storing the count because I want to do other things later with the number.

Comment: Your code is quite confusing, but I think the problem is that you are  comparing a line of text from a document with a list of strings. So it will never match

Comment: I will recommend you to simplify your code so we can focus on your problem. And don't get confused with other parts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count, you should... count.

Here, you only check if the string contains a substring.

What you should do instead is roughly the following:

```
static int count(String line, String word) {
  int count = 0;
  for (int offset = line.indexOf(word); offset >= 0; offset = line.indexOf(word, offset + 1 + word.length())) {
    count++;
  }
  return count;
}
```

Now, of course, you probably have to take into account the fact that you're looking for substrings and not words. But then if you already learned that, you might want to use regular expressions to help you further.